# how to get cursor location in Text widget in tkinter for "find and find all" function and convert into index for text editor

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
pos = TextArea.search(s, startidx2, stopindex=END)
            if not pos:
                showinfo('Notepad',f"{s} not found")
            else:
                lastidx = "%s + %dc"%(pos,len(s))
                TextArea.tag_add('found', pos,lastidx)
                TextArea.tag_config('found', foreground='white', background='blue')
                startidx2 = lastidx
```

Comment: Please give a brief description on what you want

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter uses a mark named `"insert"` to represent the position of the insertion cursor. If you want to convert that to a numerical index you can use the `index` method:

```
index = TextArea.index("insert")
```